# How can I export my tests results from docker container to a directory on the host machine

Tags: docker, allure

I run some tests inside a docker container, at the end, test reports get generated in a directory called 'allure_test_results' and I would like those report to be available on the host machine.

1.Command in a bash file that I run as an entrypoint in a docker file:

`behave -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -o allure_test_results service/features/`

2.The docker image will also be ran in Jenkins CI and I would like the same thing to happen.

3.Solutions I tried (container is not running):

`docker cp <container ID>:/allure_test_results/ allure_test_results/`

`docker run <image id> cp /allure_test_results/:/<repo root>/allure_test_results/`

PS. It would be great if the copy can be done inside dockerfile or docker-compose

I would really appreciate any help.
Thank you guys so much

Comment: Can you map a volume (a local folder mapped to the container folder where the tests’ output is written) with the -v parameter of docker?

Answer (score 2):

I just figure it out. Thank you great community.
I added this to docker compose file:

`volumes:
      - ./<host dir>/:/<container dir>/allure_test_results/`

Answer (score 2):

You can map the internal directories with host directories. In simple docker use the following

```
docker run -v <host_directory_path>:/allure_test_results/ allure_test_results docker_image:tag
```

In docker compose use the volumes mapping as Aziz said.

```
Volumes:
  - <host_directory_path>:/allure_test_results/ allure_test_results
```

Answer (score 1):

Volume mounting is the option in docker :

docker run -v Jenkins _workspace path:/allure_test_results

we will map volume to jenkins workspace and the you can publish those results bin jenkins

Answer (score 1):

Check this docker container:

https://github.com/fescobar/allure-docker-service

https://github.com/fescobar/allure-docker-service/tree/master/allure-docker-python-behave-example